# Send commands to a system using UDP protocol in python

Tags: python, udp

I have a zynq core board with its own processor , the zynq has hardcoded testfunctions which upon receiving the associated command for a function returns the data requested for example command 200 returns temperature sensor data . Using UDP in python I want to send commands to the zynq board.

Also the function will be called only upon defining the function parameters , MessageID is the command to be excuted , UniqueId and Overload is just a random number and Subgroup and SensorIndex are the inbuilt or fixed ids in the zyng for example group 0 and index 1 , this functions I have defined in another script called testfunctions  def systemMonitorGetSensor(MessageID, UniqueID, Overload, Subgroup, SensorIndex):

```
import socket
import os
import testfunctions as test

def main(self):
def openconnection():

    UDP_IP = "172.29.11.113"  # Get local machine name
    UDP_PORT = 4711  # Reserve a port for your service
    MESSAGE = b"Hello SCE100...python talking"
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

def ping():

    UDP_IP = "172.29.11.113"
    response = os.system('ping -c 1 ' + UDP_IP)
    if response == 0:
        print(UDP_IP, 'is up')
    else:
        print(UDP_IP, 'is down')

def stopsocket(self):
    self.sock.shutdown(socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    self.sock.closes()



openconnection()
ping()

MessageID = int(input("Enter the TaskID to be executed : "))
print(MessageID)
main ( MessageID )



if MessageID == 200:
test.systemMonitorGetAllSensors(200,0,0)

if MessageID == 201:
systemMonitorResponce()
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? An error or wrong output? Please clarify.

Comment: The problem is that the command is not been sent to the host(zynq board) .

Comment: Assume code posted is a snippet. main() has no body so this won't run as-is. Also `def stopsocket(self)` suggests it is part of a class but there is no class def defined. Would be helpful if you added the output when running your code.